# Track Ad Revenue from BigQuery linked with GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, admob

I'm trying to track total ad revenue from BigQuery, which is linked with GA4.
I already link GA4 with BigQuery and currently get bunch of events.
But i have no idea which event is related to ad revenue.
What i ultimately wanted to do is, querying sum of ad revenue for each day.

The event table's schema looks like below.
[image]

Comment: You can export the monetization report [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9786881?hl=en). This information is not exported to the BigQuery export as I could check.

Comment: I've tried user_ltv.revenue to get ad revenue, but it returns 'null' for all values, looks like it is only for in-app-purchases